Vue3 + vue-router + Keep-alive doesn't cache individual article pages by slug in simple blog setup
(I imagine this is a duplicate but I couldn't find anything after searching)
The Problem
I'm making an SPA blog with a listing and article pages. Simple template structure:
App.vue
  - Listing.vue --> calls API in onMounted() to get list of articles.
  - Article.vue --> calls API in onMounted() to get details of clicked article.

I have the router working, but when I try to use keep-alive to cache each article, it caches/keeps-alive the component itself (expected behavior).
However, when clicking from "Listing" --> "Article A" --> "Listing" --> "Article B", Article B's slug is in the URL but it shows Article A's content. My expectation would be that Article A's component instance gets cached and not reused for Article B.
Router file:
// routes.js
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router';
import Listing from './Listing.vue';

export default createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    strict: true,
    routes: [
        {
            name: 'listing', 
            path: '/', 
            component: Listing
        },
        {
            name: 'article', 
            path: '/:slug', 
            props: true,
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "article" */ './Article.vue'),
        },
    ],
}};

App.vue
<template>
   <div>
      <!-- header, nav, etc. -->

      <RouterView v-slot="{Component}">
         <KeepAlive>
            <component :is="Component" />
         </KeepAlive>
      </RouterView>
   </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
   name: 'App'
}
</script>


// the child templates Listing.vue and Article.vue call the API from their `onMounted()` method to fetch the data.

With the above setup, clicking on Article A in the listing shows Article A's content. However, if I go back to the listing and click on Article B, it shows Article A's content instead of B's.
What I've tried so far
What's shown above appears in Vue-router's docs and on millions of dev blogs talking about keep-alive, but rarely are there examples of anything beyond this.
My thinking is that keep-alive is caching the component itself. So, by switching from slug article-a to article-b, the router sees a match for the article route and sends back the Article component that's already been cached with Article A's content.
I started thinking maybe <component> just needed a :key attribute to distinguish one article's component instance from another, so I've tried all sorts of combinations a lá:
<RouterView v-slot="{Component}">
   <KeepAlive>
      <component :is="Component" :key="$route.path" />
   </KeepAlive>
</RouterView>

and
<RouterView v-slot="{Component, route}">
   <KeepAlive>
      <component :is="Component" :key="route.params.slug" />
   </KeepAlive>
</RouterView>

At first, this appears to work: click on "Article A" and it shows A's content; go back to the listing and click "Article B" and it shows B's content. But if I go back to "Article A", it now shows B's content on Article A's page. And if I go back and click on "Article C", it shows C's content, but it also now shows C's content for articles A and B! Basically, the last article that wasn't previously visited gets cached and shown for all articles that have been visited.
Also worth noting is that the slugs change correctly in the browser's URL. If I output the route's path in each child template like:
<template>
    <!-- Listing.vue -->
    <div>
        <p>LISTING template: <code>{{ route.path }}</code></p>

        <!-- other template code, etc. -->
    </div>
</template>


<template>
    <!-- Article.vue -->
    <div>
        <p>ARTICLE template: <code>{{ route.path }}</code></p>

        <!-- other template code, etc. -->
    </div>
</template>

{{ route.path }} updates the correct slug on the page for the listing and every article, even though they are supposedly in the cached component.
Both of my Listing.vue and Article.vue components are named. I've tried "including" them like <KeepAlive include="Listing,Article"> but I don't see any effect.
What I expect to happen
I want to "keep alive" Article A, even when the user visits Article B in the same session. I don't want to cache the Article component for all articles, and I don't want to repeatedly call my API every time an article's visited in the same session.
